# Micro-ORM with a commercial license

Tags: c#-4.0, orm

I need a Micro-ORM which has a commercial license. Our corporate policy currently does not allow open source.

I have looked at these options, which would all work, but they are all open source:
 [Dapper (Apache 2.0)](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) 
 [PetaPoco (Apache 2.0)](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)
 
 [Massive (BSD-2).](http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive)

We are using SQLite and .NET 4.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. We would be willing to purchase a commercial license if it were available.

Comment: Why do you and your legal team think "open source" means "not allowed for commercial use?" AFAIK, it depends on the license, not on whether it is open sourced or close sourced. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can buy support and have a commercial license from some companies for the open source options you are considering.

It seems that avoiding open source software is more and more difficult (and I am happy of that).

Comment: + 1 for "It seems that avoiding open source software is more and more difficult (and I am happy of that)"

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has an ORM which looks good.

But I am still a big fan of Dapper ORM. I am working with my legal department to get approval to use it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed

lightspeed is that easy compared to Entity framework that I would count it as semi-orm lite ;-)